# Indexing a list inside a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I would like an example of indexing the list of ints found in the column of "Hsplit" (see image below). My intent is to delete the first entry of each list.

I have used print statements to try indexing, such as:
for i in data.[[0,'Hsplit']] or data.[['Hsplit'],[0]]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) accessor:

```
>>> data["HSplit"].str[1:]
```

Comment: That appeared to give me the second entry, I changed to data["HSplit"].str[:1]

Comment: You said you wanted to "delete the first entry of each list".

Comment: Yes, I was incorrect. Thanks for your response.